# Paired Polarized Electrolytic Capacitor to Form Non-Polarized

Tags: capacitor

A quickie...

I needed a 1uf non polarised cap for a circuit which I didn't have so I found info that said I could join the + of two polarised caps and connect the two - terminals into the circuit to create a non polarised electrolytic cap.

I understand I should not exceed the reverse breakdown voltage in either direction and that the capacitance will be halved but are there any other issues (I also understand electrolytics are leaky)

Bash me by all means

Comment: you could tie the negative leads together and you get a non-polar cap. It will be 1/2 the capacitance (if both caps are the same) and twice its ESR. The nonpolar electrolytic caps typically have higher ESR because this is how they are normally constructed.